# AVPlayer Logging Mechanism - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, background, avplayer

I am implementing a music player with AVPlayer not AVAudioPlayer.

My aim is to play music in background forever :) (ignore call interrupt) just put the device and connect with lightning and listen.

What are the possible reasons that might Player make stop and where I need to put the log to identify the reason?

I have tried putting

applicationWillTerminate in App Delegate, but somewhere else?

BR,

Erdem

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/RefiningTheUserExperience/RefiningTheUserExperience.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016757-CH6-SW11). The "Responding to Interruptions" section. You should register for the AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification.

You can make a log when the notification arrives.

Possible reasons for the player to stop are a phone call, some alarm sound or another apps audio session that started.